# advice on modifying a module

Tags: drupal

I'm pretty much stuck here. I'm looking at this module and i'm looking at one file and another, but i'm still lost.

I'm new to Drupal but not programming.

But this is a grade up for me compared to the smaller projects i've worked on.

I'm looking at the Quiz module but having a hard time figuring how to go about modifying it to my liking.

Any tips or hints on how to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/node/508) should tell you what to expect and where to expect it. It's particularly important to read about [hooks](http://drupal.org/node/292). You may also want to [decrypt the .info file](http://drupal.org/node/542202).